# Beginner at Java through APCS first post. Is my Java program actually executable after compiling correctly? I think I may be somehow stuck in a loop

Tags: java, arrays

This chapter of the course is teaching us about methods in Java, more specifically returning values. While the rubric called for it to just be able to apply values from a .txt list the 9 [planets](https://youtu.be/N4U6inRTaow) provided below the program. I wanted to go beyond and make it so that there would be no limit on the amount of celestial bodies this could apply to (as I did with the program that created the .txt as an output). I have a finished program by another student available to me. However, I'd rather try approaching it in another way(Though I must thank Omar because I had no idea you could return arrays from methods).

Currently, as is, the program compiles without any errors in **BlueJ**. However, It does not run, or even put out any test print statements I put in. It's been running for over an hour on core 2 of my overclocked i5, but nothing. Since the core is being stressed, I assume it's stuck in a loop somehow?

How may I solve this issue?

I really appreciate any advice, and hope to spend more time here in the future.

```
/**
 * 7.04 This program will take gravity and textual data from a .txt 
 * and will perform calculations with it once I figure out how that may be done.
 *
 *
 * @author ********
 * @version (The Date)
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Weight2
{
    // write static methods here
    // Note: formula for finding weight on a planet:  Earth weight divided by Gravity constant times surface gravity
    public static String[] getData(int arraylength,int i, int value) {

      String [] Gravityscan = new String[arraylength];  //Initiates String Arrays to be used
      String [] pregravity = new String[arraylength];
      String [] names = new String[arraylength];
      String [] prevalues = new String[arraylength];
      String [] error = {"error"};
      String delims = "[    |\\ ]+";                    // Sets Delimiters

      File data2 = new File("Gravityoutput.txt");        //Opens data source
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner("Gravityoutput.txt");


      for(int m = 0; m < arraylength ; m++)
      {
           Gravityscan[m] = inFile.nextLine();                 //String for each line being run
           prevalues = Gravityscan[m].split(delims);           //Split into two (gravity name)

           pregravity[m] = prevalues[0];                       //Sorts gravity string to array
           names[m]= prevalues[1];                          //Sorts name string to array
        }
       inFile.close(); 
       //if (value == 0){return Integer.toString(arraylength);}
       if (value == 1){return pregravity;}     //Returns pregravity string for first part of loop below
       else if (value == 2){return names;}  //Returns names to end of for string below
       else {System.out.print("AN ERROR HAS OCCURED IN METHOD GETDATA"); return error;}
    }


    //public static double calcWeight() {
    //}

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);//Scanner activated

       File data = new File("Gravityoutput.txt");        //Select file to get data from
       Scanner inFile = new Scanner("Gravityoutput.txt");
      int arraylength = 0;                               //Works with loop to determine length of data
      while (inFile.hasNext()) 
        {
         arraylength++;

         }
       inFile.close();                                   //Closes file
       System.out.print("arraylength is " + arraylength);//Beta testing check

       double [] gravities = new double[arraylength];    //Declaring double array for after string conversion
       //String[] names = new String[arraylength];         //Declaring array to be used for names

       System.out.print("Please enter your mass on Earth in lbs: "); //User input for math
       double earthWeight = in.nextDouble(); 



        for(int i=0; i < arraylength; i++)
        {
        int value = 1;

        String[] stringgravity = getData(arraylength, i, value);
        gravities[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringgravity[i]);


        System.out.print(gravities[i] + " gravity  ");
        value++;
        String[] names = getData(arraylength, i, value);
        System.out.println(names[i] + "gravity");


        // static method you write Double.parseDouble

       }
        //double[] weight = calcWeight(earthWeight, gravity);  // static method you write
        //printResults(names, gravity, weight);                     // static method you write

    } //end main
}//end class
```

//Below is the data contained by Gravityoutput.txt

```
  3.70              Mercury             
  8.87              Venus               
  9.82              Earth               
  3.70              Mars                
  24.78             Jupiter             
  10.44             Saturn              
  8.86              Uranus              
  11.13             Neptune             
  0.61              Pluto
```

Comment: Using a line by line debugger (which I believe blueJ has) allows you to step through the program seeing what it's doing. That's the right tool to diagnose this sort of thing

Comment: That's actually a tool I wish I had known about on my earlier assignments. Would have helped me get around some logical errors faster. I'm going to be using the line by line debugger extensively!

Comment: They are awesome! Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of `Scanner` with `Scanner inFile = new Scanner("Gravityoutput.txt");` does not read input from the file, it reads input from the String "Gravityoutput.txt".

Try `Scanner inFile = new Scanner(data);` instead.

Oh, and your code is stuck in a loop :

`inFile.hasNext()` always returns true, since you never read anything from the `Scanner`.

You can replace it with

```
  while (inFile.hasNext()) 
  {
      String str = inFile.next();
      arraylength++;
  }
```

Comment: That looks like it will be it Eran. I wasn't aware that the information of the file would be put into a string or that hasNext() will always return true. I understand now and will comment the results once I can get to a computer!

Comment: @NickanHussaini `I wasn't aware that the information of the file would be put into a string` - That's not what's happening, the constructor of `Scanner` that takes a `String` argument uses that `String` as the input source. It doesn't treat that `String` as a name of a file. For getting the input from a File, there's a constructor that takes a `File` argument.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion! Thank you, everything makes absolute sense now.